# Blender won't open .blend file, gives an error that the file format is not supported

Tags: error, file-format

I’m experiencing an issue with a file not being able to open. I created a project in Blender back in July that I had spent many hours working on, but got busy and wasn’t able to finish. I came back to work on it today, and when I try to open it (or it’s .blend1 file) I get an error stating “Report: Error. File format is not supported in file ‘(where my file is saved)’”

Since I have used blender between now and the last time I opened this specific file, I don’t have an autosave option for it, which is the only solution I’ve seen offered for this issue online. I had backed this file and a couple others up back in August, but that back up has the same issue despite every other file I own still working fine.

I’ve been using Blender 2.91.0 this whole time.

Does anyone know what might be wrong with my file or if there is anything I could do to fix it?

Comment: Do a search for *.blend1 files these are backup copies of blender files

Comment: I had already found the .blend1 file, it gives the same error upon opening as a backup from within blender as the main .blend file does. I tried appending both the .blend file and the .blend1 file into a new file, but they were both empty folders in the append menu ): I'm thinking the file may have corrupted, but if anyone has any other suggestions I'd love to try them too